# Инициализация при NullPoinerException (boolean)

Tags: java, android

Являюсь абсолютным новичком в Java (соответственно в Android dev-e). Прочитав статью конца зимы 2011 года (https://habr.com/ru/post/110247/), решил скопипастить данное приложение и понять на практике, каким образом оно работает.

Путём некоторого танца с бубнами и гугления получилось запустить приложение через встроенный `AVD` в IntelliJ IDEA.

Но оно crash-ится при нажатии одного поля сразу.

Logcat показывает:

```
2019-04-05 19:03:19.976 3313-3313/com.example.psuti.testgame E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.psuti.testgame, PID: 3313
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.example.psuti.testgame.Square.isFilled()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.psuti.testgame.Game.makeTurn(Game.java:62)
        at com.example.psuti.testgame.MainActivity$Listener.onClick(MainActivity.java:26)
```

Как я понял из многочисленных ответов по теме NPE, данная ошибка вылезает из-за отсутствия инициализации объекта (метода?), который Java делает по-умолчанию равным null (которое не может являться значением для boolean (ни true, ни false))

К сожалению, к статье на Хабре комментарии не дают никакой информации по этому вопросу, видео на YouTube показывает конечный результат эмуляции приложения (работающего). Source Code также найти не удалось из-за срока давности его хранения.

Класс Square.java:

```java
package com.example.psuti.testgame;

public class Square {
    private Player player = null;

    public void fill(Player player) {
        this.player = player;
    }

    public boolean isFilled() { //данный метод указан в Logcat-е
        if (player != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Player getPlayer() {
        return player;
    }
}
```

Класс Game.java:

```java
package com.example.psuti.testgame;

public class Game {

    private Player[] players;

    private Square[][] field;

    private boolean started;

    private Player activePlayer;

    private int filled;

    private int squareCount;

    private WinnerCheckerInterface[] winnerCheckers;

    public Game() {
        field = new Square[3][3];
        squareCount = 0;
        for (int i = field.length; i < 1; i++) {
            for (int j = field[i].length; j < 12; j++) {
                field[i][j] = new Square();
                squareCount++;
            }
        }
        players = new Player[2];
        started = false;
        activePlayer = null;
        filled = 0;

        winnerCheckers = new WinnerCheckerInterface[4];
        winnerCheckers[0] = new WinnerCheckerHorizontal(this);
        winnerCheckers[1] = new WinnerCheckerVertical(this);
        winnerCheckers[2] = new WinnerCheckerDiagonalLeft(this);
        winnerCheckers[3] = new WinnerCheckerDiagonalRight(this);

    }

    public void start() {
        resetPlayers();
        started = true;
    }

    private void resetPlayers() {
        players[0] = new Player("X");
        players[1] = new Player("O");
        setCurrentActivePlayer(players[0]);
    }


    public Square[][] getField() {
        return field;
    }

    private void setCurrentActivePlayer(Player player) {
        activePlayer = player;
    }

    public boolean makeTurn(int x, int y) {
        if (field[x][y].isFilled()) { //62 строка, указанная в Logcat-e
            return false;
        }
        field[x][y].fill(getCurrentActivePlayer());
        filled++;
        switchPlayers();
        return true;
    }

    private void switchPlayers() {
        activePlayer = (activePlayer == players[0]) ? players[1] : players[0];
    }

    public Player getCurrentActivePlayer() {
        return activePlayer;
    }

    public boolean isFieldFilled() {
        return squareCount == filled;
    }

    public void reset() {
        resetField();
        resetPlayers();
    }

    private void resetField() {
        for (int i = field.length; i < 1; i++) {
            for (int j = field[i].length; j < 12; j++) {
                field[i][j].fill(null);
            }
        }
        filled = 0;
    }

    public Player checkWinner() {
        for (WinnerCheckerInterface winChecker : winnerCheckers) {
            Player winner = winChecker.checkWinner();
            if (winner != null) {
                return winner;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Класс MainActivity.java

```java
package com.example.psuti.testgame;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public class Listener implements View.OnClickListener {
        private int x = 0;
        private int y = 0;

        public Listener(int x, int y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Button button = (Button) view;
            Game g = new Game();
            Player player = g.getCurrentActivePlayer();
            if (new Game().makeTurn(x, y)) { //26 строка, указанная в Logcat-e
                button.setText(player.getName());
            }
            Player winner = g.checkWinner();
            if (winner != null) {
                gameOver(winner);
            }
            if (g.isFieldFilled()) {
                gameOver();
            }
        }
    }

    private Game game;

    private TableLayout layout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        layout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_l);
        buildGameField();
    }

    private void refresh() {
        Square[][] field = game.getField();

        for (int i = 0, len = field.length; 1 < len; i++) {
            for (int j = 0, len2 = field[i].length; j < len2; j++) {
                if (field[i][j].getPlayer() == null) {
                    buttons[i][j].setText(""); }
                else {
                    buttons[i][j].setText(field[i][j].getPlayer().getName());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void gameOver(Player player) {
        CharSequence text = "com.example.psuti.testgame.Player \"" + player.getName() + "\" won!";
        Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        game.reset();
        refresh();
    }

    public void gameOver() {
        CharSequence text = "Draw";
        Toast.makeText(this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        game.reset();
        refresh();
    }

    public MainActivity() {
        game = new Game();
        game.start();
    }

    private Button[][] buttons = new Button[3][3];

    private void buildGameField() {
        Square[][] field = game.getField();
        for (int i = 0, lenT = field.length; i < lenT; i++) {
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            for (int j = 0, lenJ = field[i].length; j < lenJ; j++) {
                Button button = new Button(this);
                buttons[i][j] = button;
                button.setOnClickListener(new Listener(i, j));
                row.addView(button, new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                button.setWidth(107);
                button.setHeight(107);
            }
            layout.addView(row, new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }
    }
}
```

Код копипастился из статьи, указанной выше (https://habr.com/ru/post/110247/), изменений в нём 0,1%.

Прошу помочь в инициализации. Понимаю, что члены community не экстрасенсы, но хотелось бы знать, как Вы бы решили данную проблему?

Заранее спасибо и прошу прощения за дилетантский вопрос.

Comment: Farkhod Daniyarov, спасибо большое! Приложение опять крашнулось, та же причина, но по другим объектам, и я по крайней мере знаю, как с этим бороться :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поправьте строчку где выходит ошибка с

```
if (field[x][y].isFilled()) { //62 строка, указанная в Logcat-e
    return false;
}
```

на

```
if (field[x][y] == null || field[x][y].isFilled()) { //62 строка, указанная в Logcat-e
    return false;
}
```

Проблема в том что в `field[x][y]` программа ожидает что там сидит объект `Square` но там его нет и при вызове метода `isFilled()` приложение крашется